# Long running process freezing UI, how to update with threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I've written this sample code for a long running process, but the Windows Form freezes until the process completes. How do I change the code so that the work runs in parallel?

```
var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
{
    textBox1.Text = "Enter Thread";
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        //My Long Running Work
    }
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "After Loop";
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, ui);
```

Comment: Try not using the synchronization context to run it on, which means you need to start a sub-task to update the GUI, or use invoke.

Comment: if I remove "ui" parameter it thrown a "Cross-Thread" exception

Answer (score 6):

You can use a continuation. I don't remember the exact syntax but it's something like:

```
textBox1.Text = "Enter Thread"; //assuming here we're on the UI thread
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
{                
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        //My Long Running Work
    }
    return result;
})
.ContinueWith(ret => textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + result, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

An alternative would be something like:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
{
    YourForm.Invoke((Action)(() => textBox1.Text = "Enter Thread");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        //My Long Running Work
    }
    YourForm.Invoke((Action)(() => textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + result);}, 
        CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None);
```

Again, I don't remember the exact syntax but the idea is that you want to perform the long operation on a thread **different than the UI thread**, but report progress (including completion) on the UI thread.

By the way, the [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class would work very well here, too (I personally like it very much).

Comment: That' Ok Man.thanks alot.How I can return value from t to updater Action?Thanks man thanks

Comment: @Nima - See my edit. I suggest you read a simple turotial, for example :http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/01/25/NET-40-and-SystemThreadingTasks.aspx