# Problem with Task.Factory.StartNew and open Form From External Assembly

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a main Windows Application Project and another Class library application. In the class library app, I have a form (created programatically) that shows in main windows application project after long running work.

I want to show that form (in class library) asynchronously.

I wrote this code for Main Application Project:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
            {

                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke((Action)(() => textBox1.Text += "Enter Task"));
                    this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            ExternalAssembly.OpenForm of = new ExternalAssembly.OpenForm();
                            of.ShowWindow();
                        })); 
                }

                this.Invoke((Action)(() => textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Exit Task"));
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None);
```

and in class library:

```
public class OpenForm
    {
        public void ShowWindow()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

But when the form in the class library shows, my main form freezes. How I can change the code so that showing a form in another assembly is asynchronous?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with Task.Factory.StartNew and Updating UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526713/problem-with-task-factory-startnew-and-updating-ui)

Comment: No it's not duplicat of that post.this post point to "External Assembly".thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've started a background task by using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. You've then, in that background task, used `Invoke`. This runs the action on the foreground thread, blocking the background thread until it's completed.

Since the code you're invoking (`ShowWindow`) takes a long time, you've successfully blocked both foreground and background threads.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
this.textBox1.Text += "Enter Task";
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
                {
                    var of = new ExternalAssembly.OpenForm();
                    of.ShowWindow();
                }).ContinueWith(o => Invoke(new Action(() => this.textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Exit Task"))
            );
```