# returning result from an extra thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to make the `result` (Returning result of the heavy process) accessible after executing the `Heavy Process` in an extra thread, As it's mainly expected do not want during the process UI took effect,
After the process is done could play with the `result`

*During some searches, and looking at my articles I got that there are **several approaches** to
make this happen, please provide the best approach you knew or use in a similar situation*

*this is a sample which I want to deal with in the best possible approach :*

```
        public ACollection DoProcess(Document docProcess) 
        {
            ACollection result = new ACollection ();

            ThreadStart threadStart = delegate
            {
                result = MyProcess(docProcess);
            };
            var threadProcess = new Thread(threadStart);
            threadProcess.Start();    

            return result ;
}
```

Other possible approaches could be IAsyncResult, BackgroundWorker, Using Timers and checking the states, instead of returning the result to a method to handle it and report it to the UI send it directly in a thread-safe manner to our UI Controls ...

Please give your own opinion and sample in a similar case,
thanks in advance

**Edit 3: Approach - Based on Brian's Answer**

```
        LenzCollection myResultCollection = new LenzCollection();       

        TaskScheduler ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
              myResultCollection = DoCollect(docProcess);
              //Task.WaitAll();

              return myResultCollection;
          }).ContinueWith((task =>
          {
              myResultCollection = task.Result;
          }), ui);

        return myResultCollection;
```

It still didn't wait and won't give the desired result

Comment: `while (threadProcess.IsAlive) { }` makes this single-threaded. And a CPU-hog.

Comment: I got a few minutes later and edited, thanks, but still needs to know your suggested reusable approach, thx

Comment: BackgroundWorker already got all the functionality you asked about. So why trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: To have the coding style of some modules remain the same as what they were before and make them reusable this way, maybe I'm wrong but I think when you want to go for BackgrounndWorker the reusability of your code will be sacrificed, Am I right or wrong ?

Comment: Really the judgement between 2 of the answers is hard for me at this time , I voted every participant UP, about the chosen answer I will decide after testing Tigran's Method, that was new for me, and I like Raphael's answer also because Events were my friends and the implementation was good and gives you the flexibility you need, I should go and will return after 2-3 hours and will play with the suggested methods to see which will be best in this case, thanks everyone,really helped ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1:**

Use the `Task` class and the `ContinueWith` method.

```
TaskScheduler ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    var result = MyProcess(docProcess);
    return result.ToString();
  }).ContinueWith((task =>
  {
    textBox1.Text = task.Result;
  }, ui);
```

You have to remember to pass in the correct synchronization context into the `ContinueWith` method. You can see how I did that with the `ui` variable.

**Option #2:**

Use the new `async` and `await` keywords.<sup>1</sup>

```
private async void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  textBox1.Text = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      var result = MyProcess(docProcess);
      return result.ToString();
    });
}
```

Clearly this is a lot easier on the eyes and does all of the marshaling and synchronization context stuff for you.

---

<sup>1</sup>*The new keywords will be available in C# 5.0, but you can use them now via the [Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9983). The CTP uses `TaskEx` instead of `Task`.*

Comment: This is another clever answer here, I like it, this is no problem even better for me if it is based on C# 5.0 which could be applicable now any how, thanks for the post, I'll be back in minutes, test it and will talk you about it if needed, +1 thank you for participated inv :)

Comment: I tested both methods before I posted so they should work. Just remember if using the second method via the Async CTP that you need use `TaskEx.Run` instead of `Task.Run`. That's just a CTP thing though.

Comment: Yes I see, I want to adapt myself and my code with it, and ask you if needed :)

Comment: I got this error : A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

Comment: Used the 1st mentioned approach, when you were here please let me know, thanks

Comment: @Sypress: Perhaps your `MyProcess` method is throwing an exception. Wrap it with a try-catch and handle the exception accordingly.

Comment: First approach seems not waiting for the result to prepared

Comment: Will try to make it suit my needs within next 12h, thanks for your answer and help, maybe it's the best answer of it's kind. I think debugging my recent code will lead me to the working code.

Comment: My friend I edited the post based on your advices and coding the first approach you mentioned, It won't do the heavy process (here : DoCollect) and give the correct result here(myResultCollection is empty when it wants to return it at the end of the method), please mind

Comment: @Sypress: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The solutions I give in my answer do **not** wait for the task to complete. That is both intentional and important. You don't want the UI thread to ever wait for anything. The `ContinueWith` stuff is what transfers the result to the UI thread.

Comment: In my Edited Post, look at this line please : myResultCollection = DoCollect(docProcess);

Comment: It should have a complete result dependent to DoCollect(docProcess) completion, when it reaches to this : "return myResultCollection; ", myResultCollection is empty !

Comment: @Sypress: Sounds like a problem with `DoCollect` then. That would be a separate problem unrelated to the `Task` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Just implement an Event, which you register before you Execute the method. And let the method raise the Event, when finished.

For Example:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(string result);
public class MyClass
{
  public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
  private void Event(string result)
  {
    MyEventHandler handler = MyEvent;
    if(handler != null)
      handler(result);
  }

  public void DoSomethingLong()
  {
    //Do something
    Event("Finish");
  }
}
```

Now you can run this like

```
MyClass.Event += MyEventHandler(On_Event);
Thread t = new Thread(MyClass.DoSomethingLong);
t.Start();    

void On_Event(string result)
{
  //Get executed when finished;
}
```

An Example for invoking to UI Thread

```
void On_Event(string result)
{
  if(this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    MyEventHandler handler = new MyEventHandler(On_Event);
    Invoke(handler, new object[] { result });
    return;
  }
  // At this point you can access your UI without having Cross-Threaded operation!
}
```

Comment: I'll check it and think it could be a reusable piece of code, As events in general, really thanks, Does it have any drawbacks ? how do you compare it with BackgroundWorker ?

Comment: I would say, you're more flexible with your own implementation of events. You can raise events everytime you want, and can update like this your UI without freezing. Maybe one Point you have to watch, if an Event gets raised the Methods where you registered the Event (in my Example On_Event) gets execute in the Thread of the Method. So if you want update your UI, you have to Invoke in your UI Thread.. I Edit my post and give you an Example for this too!

Comment: please give me some hours to test them, I will use your advices and appreciate them, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In a desktop (WinForms/WPF) app the best and easiest approach is a BackgroundWorker. It was designed to handle this.

Comment: In lots of articles I saw that it's recommended in most of similar problems, but you know I want to have more authority in the way I use my made modules, this way I should join some separated piece of code and reshape the module/structure of the code, if that be a necessity and no pieces of code could challange it , so I'll do, Anyway will be glad and appreciated if any suggested code example you could give in my situation

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `.NET Framework 4.0 or +`, you can run the process from another thread and process in [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx), for example

```
Process pro = null; 
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
   pro =new Process(..);
   pro.Start(); 
   pro.WaitForExit(); 
}).ContinueWith(..process data recieved from the pro)
```

*EDIT*

Do not use `while(...)`, but use `pro.WaitForExit()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this the best approach in this case ? I wasn't familiar with this, and think it could be useful, For using this is the provided code possible to use in my example ?

Comment: @Sypress: Is this is a *best* or not should decide *you* :) This is *modern* approach and most compact one, in this case. Do not need declare event, handle them, or define BackgroundWorker. I suggest you to try it (copy/paste) to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: I see, Maybe silly but it is really knew and I couldn't bring/convert my code into it :D, if "pro" is the heavyProcess I mentioned above where is my instance "result" I know it should be simple for you but could you please provide my instances in it and make it easier for me to move my code based on it, really thanks for this modern approach ;)

Comment: @Sypress: the code is this that you see atually. 1) You run process in another thread and wait for its end on the *same thread*, so UI (main thread) is not blocked. 2) One time process exited, thread finished, so the method written inside ContinueWith closure will be executed. So insied ContinueWith you can put a method you use tio process a results of your process.

Comment: please give me some hours to test them, I will use your advices and appreciate them, thanks alot

Comment: At first I had to go, but it cancelled and I'm working on this approach, I edited my code, please review the question and correct me

Comment: Please look at my edited post my friend, The form I'm trying to use is incorrect : "new Process(DoCollect(docProcess))" and "ContinueWith(wc);" how should I change them, for the second part I think I should use lambda but I recently moved to it and Linq and don't know how exactly to shape it, for the "process" line I got this error : Error 1 'System.Diagnostics.Process' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: in ContinueWith us like ContinueWith(()=> { your code here that reads result });

Comment: seems this is incorrect : "Process(myProcess(docProcess)", same error as I mentioned earlier

Comment: Dear Tigran Clarified the problem in Edit 2

Comment: @Sypress: use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to start a process. It's not absolutely clear how you gonna read the data from the file.

Comment: my friend maybe there is a misunderstanding, I have these Items(variables/instances used in my code ) : myResult (a custom defined collection) as the result of the myProcess ( a custom method do the heavy process, myListBox a listbox to place the gathered result(myResult.Items) to it

Comment: I know what is the Process.Start but didn't use Tasks and Parallel Dev, Could they do the job I wanted or we are away ?

Comment: @Sypress: sure they can ! Just read a little bit about Task<T> and UI management, can have a look also here [Problem with Task.Factory.StartNew and Updating UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526713/problem-with-task-factory-startnew-and-updating-ui). It's not something that can be explained in a couple of lines, but it worths to spend a time on it to become more familiar. Good luck.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10045/discussion-between-sypress-and-tigran)

Comment: Thanks again my friend for giving me the idea and spending some time on this